# How can I get file's name from variable with its full path in python?

Tags: python, variables, path

Let's say I have `a = "C:\folder1\folder2\picture.jpg"` How can I assign variable b to file's name with its extension: b = 'picture.jpg'

Comment: `os.path.basename(mypath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without too many complications, you can just use the `os` module as follows:

```
import os
a = "C:\folder1\folder2\picture.jpg"
b = os.path.basename(a)
```

Which will output what you desire: `'picture.jpg'`